# MYSQL: Get the next 100 and the 100 previous IDs for an specific ID

Tags: mysql, mariadb

For a given ID I'd like to set up a query, that gives me the **next** 100 and the 100 **previous** IDs.
This sounds very basic, but the problem is, the IDs are not continuous. So they could go something like `3, 6, 10, 11, ...`

My first idea was creating a query like this (suppose I want this for id 100):

```
Select * from mytable where id > 200 AND id < 400
```

But obviously this does not work with the IDs not being continuous.

I am using 10.1.41 MariaDB.

Comment: Question got closed, but maybe good to mention: the solution with using UNION from the linked question in the closing message works for me.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using **mysql v8.0**. You can consider using `row_number()`.

```
select * from 
(select *, row_number() over (order by id) as rn from tableA) t1 where rn between 200 and 300
```

Comment: sounds good - but gives me a syntax error

Comment: That's what I used as query: select * from 
(select row_number() over (order by id) as rn, * from mytable) t1 where rn between 4568169 and 4568369

Comment: And are you using MySQL 8.0? Earlier versions of MySQL don't support window functions.

Comment: @stats0007, change the * to column names, or move * to front

Comment: It's actually 10.1.41-MariaDB

Comment: In MariaDB, window functions were first implemented in 10.2.0: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/

Comment: Ah ok that explains why it does not work. Thanks also for linking the other question - did not find this one.